# What is an example of meta-heuristic algorithm for solving Mario NP-hard problem?

Tags: algorithms, optimization, np-hard, heuristics

Applying entertainment with computations is my main motivation in studying Computer Science, however, I'm still a neophyte to this field. While searching across the net, I came across this paper [Classic Nintendo Games are (Computationally) Hard](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.1895.pdf), indicating that **Mario** is an *NP-Hard* problem. Given by the proof of NP-hardness in the paper, I'm wondering, can we apply metaheuristic algorithms in solving the **Mario** Problem? If yes, I would be glad if you can provide an example and show how it works.